# How is the model populated on HttpPost?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My `SomeModel` is defined as:

```
public class SomeModel
{
   public string property1 { get; set }
   public bool property2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have an action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    SomeModel model = new SomeModel();
    //... populate model ...
    return View(model);
}
```

Assume that in the view `property1` and `property2` are instanced as `@Html.EditorFor`, in which case `property1` would be rendered as a `<input type='text'>` and `property2` would be a `<input type='checkbox'>`.

If I have the following controller action to handle a submit from the Edit form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, SomeModel model, FormCollection collection)
{
}
```

How does the parameter model get populated, if ever?

Comment: Look at the collection keys, MVC uses the key names to try to map to the model. Sometimes if its having trouble you can specify the prefix's manually using the bind attribute

Comment: i think in your Edit method you only need to add just the Model as parameter. The model binder checks all your <input> html tags, and the "name" and "id" properties of them, and maps them to the entity. Also not sure about naming your "edit" method "Action".

Comment: @Alex, I corrected the mistake.  The method name should be Edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use something like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(SomeModel model)
{
    //do something
}
```

All the model binding will be taken care of for you if you use the standard Html.EditorFor syntax in your view, as you have alluded to.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property1)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property2)
```

More on Model Binding [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)